# Radius of Convergence - $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n x^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of this power series here?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n x^{n^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

The [radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) is given by
$$
\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
In this case
$$
\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(2^n\right)^{1/n^2}}=1
$$

Comment: Sir,For The power series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{f\left(n\right)}$.What
would be the radius of convergence?An analogous result suggest $\frac{1}{\limsup\limits _{n\to\infty}|a_{n}|^{1/f\left(n\right)}}$.IS
it true Always?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, one can find the radius of convergence using the root test:

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}|2^{-n}|^{1/n^2}=1.
$$

The radius of convergence is equal to $1$.

Comment: I didnt understand your second part of the answer. from where did the 2^-n come from?

Answer (score 0):

For determine the radius of convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n x^{n^2}$$

one may use the ratio test(limit version):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n+1} x^{(n+1)^2}}{2^n x^{n^2}}=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ x^{(n+1)^2}}{ x^{n^2}}=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ x^{n^2+2n+1}}{ x^{n^2}}=2\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2n+1}$$

By that test, the series converges, if

$$2\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2n+1}<1$$

or

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2n+1}<\frac{1}{2}$$

this happens when $ -1 < x < 1$.

Therefore, the radius the radius of convergence $R$, is 1.

Comment: Several misconceptions here: first, an interval is not a radius of convergence. Also $2^{n+1}/2^n \not = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've a question, how $(-1,1)$  called here, is it the 'interval of convergence'?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it would be called that way. Btw, sorry if I've been a bit rude. Oh, and the inequalities must be strict, otherwise $|x^{2n+1}| \to 1$ ;-)

Comment: Oh my God!!! !!!

Comment: It is bed time for me...