# Radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n}c_{n}z^{n^{2}}$ given that the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n}c_{n}z^{n}$ is finite and nonzero

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

I know that the radius of convergence of a given power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}$ is $R$, where $0<R<\infty$.

Given this information, I need to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n^{2}}$.

So, using the Cauchy-Hadamard, I get that $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n^{2}]{|c_{n}|} = \limsup_{n\to\infty}|c_{n}|^{1/n^{2}} = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left( |c_{n}|^{1/n}\right)^{1/n}$.

Now, I do not know how to evaluate this last $\limsup$. I've tried logarithms, and wound up back where I started.

Could somebody please tell me how to get this limit? Once I have this, I'm good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix $0<S<R<U<\infty$, then $|c_n|^{1/n}<U$ for every $n$ large enough and $|c_n|^{1/n}>S$ for infinitely many $n$ hence $|c_n|^{1/n^2}<U^{1/n}$ for every $n$ large enough and $|c_n|^{1/n^2}>S^{1/n}$ for infinitely many $n$. Now, $U^{1/n}\to1$ and $S^{1/n}\to1$ when $n\to\infty$ hence...

Comment: Off-topic? Really??? What kind of fantasy universe are you living in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some care is needed to actually understand what the coefficients of the second series are:

$$c_1z+c_2z^4+c_3z^9+\ldots\;,\;\text{ so the coefficients are}\;\begin{cases}d_n=c_{\sqrt n}\;,&\text{n is a square}\\{}\\d_n=0\;,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then we have the coefficients sequence:

$$\{d_n\}=\left\{\,c_1,0,0,c_2,0,0,0,0,c_3,0,0,0,0,0,0,c_4,0,\ldots\,\right\}$$

So you actually have to evaluate (define $\;S:=\{n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\exists\,m\in\Bbb N\;s.t.\;m^2=n\}$)

$$\lim\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\sqrt[n]{|d_n|}=\lim\sup_{n\in S}\sqrt[n]{|c_ {\sqrt n}|}$$

But since $\;\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\frac1R>0\;$ , we have some neighborhood $\;\epsilon\;$ of $\;\frac1R\;$ such that for infinitely many $\;n'$ s we have

$$\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}\in\left(\frac1R-\epsilon,\,\frac1r+\epsilon\right)\subset (0,\infty)\implies$$

for infinitely many $\;n\in S\;$ we have (observe: $\;n\in S\implies n=m^2\implies\sqrt[n]{|c_{\sqrt n}|}=\sqrt[m^2]{|c_m|}\;$)

$$\sqrt[m^2]{|c_m|}\in\left(\frac1R-\epsilon,\,\frac1r+\epsilon\right)^{1/m}\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}1$$

Comment: Actually, $d_n\ne c_n$.

Comment: @Did Thank you. What I mean to write, but perhaps wasn't clear, is that the new series is $$d_1z+d_2z^2+d_3z^3+d_4z^4+\ldots$$ and $\;d_n=0\;$ if $\;n\;$  is not a square, and $\;d_m=c_m\;$ when $\;m\;$ is a square.

Comment: @Joanpemo, you mean $d_{m}=0$ when $m$ not a square?

Comment: This isn't right. When $n$ is a square, $d_n = c_{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much. You're right, editing now:

Comment: I think this time I grabbed it. I think this is what makes this site so great some times: one can lear a lot from own mistakes!

Comment: No, the $n$'s do not line up at the end. You need $|c_n|^{1/n^2}$.

Comment: As explained in a comment to a previous question by this user: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1730132/6179

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by "the n's do not line up(?) at the end." Please explain this.

Comment: @Did aren't you, in the third comment below the question, defining the series coefficients as I did?

Comment: As you do **now**, yes.

Comment: @Did Thank you...oh, and I see now my mistake! I certainly have $\;c_n'$s there, yet their indexs aren't in the same order as the $\;n-$th root! I think Ted meant something of this kind...I'll try to save my post before erasing.

Comment: Well, this is my last attempt to salve the post. At least I learned from this now. :)